# Eclipse RCP OS-X: Either remove Preferences and About in Menubar or get notification

Tags: macos, swt, eclipse-rcp, handler, menubar

I'm developing an Eclipse RCP based application, which runs fine under OS-X and Windows.
Under OS-X I've run into the following Problem:
In the Menubar the first Menu "ApplicationName" has the default entries "About ApplicationName" and "Preferences".

I want to either grey these two out, remove them completely, or if this is not possible add a handle to get notified if they are clicked.

Thanks for help

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using? Are you on carbon/cocoa?

Answer (score 1):

See this [SWT snippet](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet354.java?view=co) (assuming you're using Cocoa). For Carbon, use [this one](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet178.java?rev=HEAD&content-type=text/vnd.viewcvs-markup).

In the new Cocoa API, it looks like you can do anything you like to the system menu items. I've only used the Carbon API, which is more of an unsupported hack.